# XSLT Removing nodes not in a list while keeping any child nodes that are in a list

Tags: xslt-1.0

I have a list of ids that I want to use to 'filter' a supplied xml file. Each node in the list should be kept, and every node not in the list removed.

The difficulty for me is when I remove a node (not in the IDList), I also end up removing a child node that may be in the IDList.

Last of all, I need to keep the nesting of the nodes (see my example below).

This is my list of IDs:

IDList = 2,3,5,6

This is my input xml is:

> ```
> <Associations>
>     <Association ASSOCIATION_ID="1">
>         Elmwood Association
>         <Homes/>
>     </Association>
>     <Association ASSOCIATION_ID="2">
>         Oakwood Association
>         <Homes/>
>         <Association ASSOCIATION_ID="4">
>             Oakwood Sub Association A
>             <Homes/>
>             <Association ASSOCIATION_ID="6">
>                 Oakwood Sub Sub Association
>                 <Homes/>
>             </Association>
>         </Association>
>         <Association ASSOCIATION_ID="5">
>             Oakwood Sub Association B
>             <Homes/>
>         </Association>
>     </Association>
>     <Association ASSOCIATION_ID="3">
>         Cedarwood Association
>         <Homes/>
>     </Association>
> </Associations>
> ```

This is my desired output:

> ```
> <Associations>
>     <Association ASSOCIATION_ID="2">
>         Oakwood Association
>         <Homes/>
>         <Association ASSOCIATION_ID="6">
>             Oakwood Sub Sub Association
>             <Homes/>
>         </Association>
>         <Association ASSOCIATION_ID="5">
>             Oakwood Sub Association B
>             <Homes/>
>         </Association>
>     </Association>
>     <Association ASSOCIATION_ID="3">
>         Cedarwood Association
>         <Homes/>
>     </Association>
> </Associations>
> ```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I. XSLT 2.0 solution:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:param name="pIds" select="2, 3, 5, 6" as="xs:integer+"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template priority="2" match=
  "Association[not(@ASSOCIATION_ID = $pIds)
             and not(.//Association[@ASSOCIATION_ID = $pIds])]"/>

 <xsl:template match=
  "Association[@ASSOCIATION_ID = $pIds]
        //Association[not(@ASSOCIATION_ID = $pIds)]
  |
   *[not(self::Association[@ASSOCIATION_ID = $pIds])]
      /node()[not(descendant-or-self::Association[@ASSOCIATION_ID = $pIds])]
  ">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<Associations>
    <Association ASSOCIATION_ID="1">
        Elmwood Association
        <Homes/>
    </Association>
    <Association ASSOCIATION_ID="2">
        Oakwood Association
        <Homes/>
        <Association ASSOCIATION_ID="4">
            Oakwood Sub Association A
            <Homes/>
            <Association ASSOCIATION_ID="6">
                Oakwood Sub Sub Association
                <Homes/>
            </Association>
        </Association>
        <Association ASSOCIATION_ID="5">
            Oakwood Sub Association B
            <Homes/>
        </Association>
    </Association>
    <Association ASSOCIATION_ID="3">
        Cedarwood Association
        <Homes/>
    </Association>
</Associations>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<Associations>
   <Association ASSOCIATION_ID="2">
        Oakwood Association
        <Homes/>
      <Association ASSOCIATION_ID="6">
                Oakwood Sub Sub Association
                <Homes/>
      </Association>
      <Association ASSOCIATION_ID="5">
            Oakwood Sub Association B
            <Homes/>
      </Association>
   </Association>
   <Association ASSOCIATION_ID="3">
        Cedarwood Association
        <Homes/>
   </Association>
</Associations>
```

---

**II. XSLT 1.0 solution:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:my="my:my">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <my:ids>
   <id>2</id>
   <id>3</id>
   <id>5</id>
   <id>6</id>
 </my:ids>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template priority="2" match=
  "Association[not(@ASSOCIATION_ID = document('')/*/my:ids/*)
             and not(.//Association[@ASSOCIATION_ID = document('')/*/my:ids/*])]"/>

 <xsl:template match=
  "Association[@ASSOCIATION_ID = document('')/*/my:ids/*]
        //Association[not(@ASSOCIATION_ID = document('')/*/my:ids/*)]
  |
   *[not(self::Association[@ASSOCIATION_ID = document('')/*/my:ids/*])]
      /node()[not(descendant-or-self::Association
                         [@ASSOCIATION_ID = document('')/*/my:ids/*])]
  ">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Dimitre, I was incorrect to specify xslt-2.0, so xslt-1.0 is the only available option (sorry!). When I try your code I only get back the association with association_Id = 2 node. Is this because I am in xslt-1.0?

Comment: @user2340911, If your XSLT 1.0 processor is a truly compliant and not buggy, you should have received a compile-time error message, or at least warning. As for converting this to XSLT 1.0, this is possible but would look rather more clumsy. I am going to work now -- will be able to have a look at an XSLT 1.0 solution about 10 hours from now.

Comment: @Schletz, I added to this answer an XSLT 1.0 solution, as requested.